# Select random rows, then sort by column from a different table

Tags: mysql

I understand how to select random rows and sort by a specific column, but my problem is I need to sort the rows by a column in a different table.

Example:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT event_id, data_id
    FROM events
    WHERE category_id=1
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 5) c
ORDER BY creation_date;
```

So this query would work fine if creation_date was in the events table, but creation_date is in a table called 'data'. So data_id in the events table is the foreign key to the data table where creation_date is.

My goal in this is to select the 5 RANDOM rows from the events table, but then sort them by the creation_date from the data table.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT 
    event_id, 
    data_id 
  FROM 
    events 
  WHERE 
    category_id = 1 
  ORDER BY RAND() 
  LIMIT 5) c 
  INNER JOIN data d ON d.data_id = c.data_id
ORDER BY 
  d.creation_date;
```